# Como enviar a data do Data Time Picker para o banco em MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio, height

Fala galera tenho um problema que é enviar o o meu `DTPentrar` vulgo `DataTimePicker`, segue foto do erro e o código, se alguém puder dar uma luz agradeço. Abraços

```
   private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            conectar.Open();

            //int DataEntrada = Convert.ToInt32(DTPEntrada.Text);


            //MessageBox.Show("Conectado");

            MySqlCommand Inserir = new MySqlCommand();
            Inserir.Connection = conectar;
            Inserir.CommandText = Inserir.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Pacote (peca, Nome, Quantidade, Data_entrada) VALUES ('"
                                    + cbxPeca.Text + "', '" + txtNome.Text + "', '"
                                    + txtQuantidade.Text + "', '" + DTPEntrada + "'); ";

            Inserir.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conectar.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Cadastro Realizado!", "Concluido",
              MessageBoxButtons.OK,
              MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            selecionarCategoria();
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Falha na conexao!", "falha",
              MessageBoxButtons.OK,
              MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem do erro acima e o código do banco a baixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui o erro, após a sugestão do @Augusto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olha, nunca trabalhei muito com `C#` mas você não teria que "tratar" sua data antes de inserir ? Não deveria estar como `2019-03-21 00:00:00` para inserção no banco ?

Comment: @8biT como eu deveria tratar minha data ? meio que sou novo na linguagem

Answer (score 3):

Tente ao invés de passar os parâmetros concatenados, passar pelo MySql.
Ou seja:

```
    Inserir.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Pacote (peca, Nome, Quantidade, Data_entrada) VALUES (@peca, @nome, @quantidade, @dataentrada)";

inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peca",cbxPeca.Text);
inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome",txtNome.Text);
inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade",txtQuantidade.Text);
inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataentrada",DTPEntrada .Text);
```

Ou até mesmo se não conseguir passar os valores diretamente dos componentes, crie uma classe de modelo, atribua os valores e passe por parâmetro para o método. PS.: Melhor forma de trabalhar.

Comment: Ah, e lembre-se de que, caso tenha te ajudado não esqueça de avaliar as respostas! :D

Comment: então eu fiz do modo como sugeriu, porém mesmo assim a informação da data não é enviada, ele diz que o valor não está correto, vou mandar a foto do erro na pergunta

Comment: já troquei também a questão do `DATETIME` no banco de dados para `DATE`

Comment: Tente então DTPEntrada.Value?

Comment: sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@dataentrada", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DTPEntrada.Value; Se mesmo assim não der certo, tente converter o campo para DateTime antes de passar o parâmetro.

Comment: A propriedade que traz a data do datapicker é o 'value'. Tente isso: inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataentrada",DTPEntrada.Value);

Comment: Valeu galera, funcionou!